# Segmentation Fault in C (gcc)

Tags: c, gcc, segmentation-fault

It compiles fine but when I try to run the program I get a segmentation fault. I"m not sure where I went wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    int i, childpid;


for (i = strlen(argv[1]); i >= 0; i --) {
    if (fork() == 0) {
        printf("%c\n",argv[1][i]);
        break;
    }
}    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `i` is getting you out of bounds. Try `i = strlen(argv[1]) - 1` (Remember that arrays in C are *zero-based*).

Comment: How do you run it? If you run it without arguments, `argv[1]` will be `NULL`.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Except that it isn't out of bounds - that pointer points to the terminating NUL byte.

Comment: If `strlen(argv[1])` is e.g. 4, then `argv[1][i]` will be `'\0'` (i.e. not out of bounds).

Comment: Check for the required no. of arguments in `argc`.

Comment: @HAL I also thought it was the case but just verified he expects to have a big string on first argument

Comment: @Mauren `argc` has the total no. of arguments to the program and NOT the length of an individual argument.

Comment: @HAL yes, this is true. He must test it anyways (since the first one will be program name), but what I meant is that he wants to parse the first argument.

Comment: @HAL put that on my answer

Comment: I would try the strlen(argv[1]) - 1, I doubt that you wish to print '\0' anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `argc` parameter to know how many arguments were sent from command-line. Test if it is bigger than 1 before running your `for` statement, since your first argument will be the program name:

```
if (argc > 1) {
    for (i = strlen(argv[1]) - 1; i >= 0; i --) {
        if (fork() == 0) {
            printf("%c\n",argv[1][i]);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

or, if you just wish to print first character, you could do something like this

```
if(argc > 1) {
    if(strlen(argv[1]) > 0 && fork() == 0) {
        printf("%c\n",argv[1][0]);
    } else {
        // for loop here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Check for the required no. of arguments in `argc`
2. A string(`char` array) has elements from  index `0` to `length - 1`

Code:

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    int i, childpid;

    if(argc < 2) {
        printf("An argument is missing\n");
        return -1;
    }

    for (i = strlen(argv[1]) - 1; i >= 0; i --) {
        if (fork() == 0) {
        printf("%c\n",argv[1][i]);
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If it works, wouldn't that mean that printf("%c\n", '\0') does a seg fault ? since it's seems the asker had a proper argv[1]. Can't test it since I'm not working on C these days.

Comment: @Lyth No, `printf("%c\n", '\0')` does not seg fault.

Answer (score -1):

What happens if `argv[1]` is length 1?

In the first loop `i` will be 1, but `argv[1][1]` is the terminating null of a one character long string.

Comment: this post should be comment

Comment: And how does this explain the segmentation fault?